# Convert string to int in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have to convert a `string` value to `int`, but it seems LINQ to Entities does not support this.

For the following code, I am getting an error.

```
var query = (from p in dc.CustomerBranch
             where p.ID == Convert.ToInt32(id) // here is the error.
             select new Location()
             {
                 Name      = p.BranchName,
                 Address   = p.Address,
                 Postcode  = p.Postcode,
                 City      = p.City,
                 Telephone = p.Telephone
             }).First();
return query;
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '`Int32 ToInt32 (System.String)`', and this method can not be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the conversion outside LINQ:

```
var idInt = Convert.ToInt32(id);
var query = (from p in dc.CustomerBranch
             where p.ID == idInt 
             select new Location()
             {
                 Name      = p.BranchName,
                 Address   = p.Address,
                 Postcode  = p.Postcode,
                 City      = p.City,
                 Telephone = p.Telephone
             }).First();
return query;
```

Comment: yes, that would definitely work :). But I wonder there must be a way to do this inside the query..

Comment: It depends on the LINQ provider what will work inside the linq and what will not (i.e whether the linq provider is able to convert the expression to under lying language or not) EF provider it doesn't support this convert expression.

Comment: @kandroid I think its not good to do it in the query, though you could possibly do `p.ID.ToString() == id`

Comment: Oh and the error is because linq is trying to convert your statement to SQL but it doesn't recognise that convert is equivalent to SQL cast, not sure if it would recognise parse as equivalent or not

Comment: Thank you guys. p.ID.ToString()==id, don't work and even int.parse(id) don't. But,I found my answer. cheers.

Comment: this is not the correct answer. The question is about the right expression syntax. Not a workaround

Comment: @abzarak  I don't see any sentence in the question that asks about "right expression syntax". If you do have the correct answer please let us know.

Answer (score -2):

No they wouldn't. Think of it this way: both `ToString()` and `Parse()` are methods on the objects. Since LINQ to Entities tries to convert your LINQ expression to SQL, those are not available.

If one needs to do this in the query, it might be possible with `Cast`, which [should be available in LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301460.aspx). In the case of `ToString`, you could use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx).

Comment: -1. Cast converts the elements of a supplied collection to the specified type. If you supply a string to Cast it will try to convert that string to an IEnumerable of requested type.