# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, int, entity, int32

I am using Entity Framework, and I have a line of code that is taking a var and translating it back to an iint for the database.

```
var record = context.enrollments.SingleOrDefault
  (row => row.userId == int.Parse(UserID) && row.classId == int.Parse(ClassID));
```

Whenever I try to run it I receive rhis error. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I have tried this as well

```
 var record = context.enrollments.FirstOrDefault
  (row => row.userId == Convert.ToInt32(UserID) 
  && row.classId == Convert.ToInt32(ClassID));
```

and all I receive is this error message, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

and finally I have tried this as well, which I know is unusual, but it has worked in the past for similar situations.

```
var record = context.enrollments.SingleOrDefault
  (row => row.userId == CommonDLL.Sanitize<int>.ConvertType(UserID) 
  && row.classId == CommonDLL.Sanitize<int>.ConvertType(ClassID));
```

In which I get this error. As you can see I have tried seveal different things and nothing is working, so any help would be great.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you _should_ be able to replace `int.Parse` with `Convert.ToInt32` to make it work.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the comments, but I have tried that and I receive this error message, "{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}"

Comment: Did you try using the full namespace like `System.Convert.ToInt32`? I don't if this is specifically something that linq doesn't support. Just guessing here.

Comment: Actually, there is already a question regarding this, with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399602/convert-string-to-int-in-linq-to-entities and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887296/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-int32system-string-meth

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in `Linq to Entity`, you should use the methods in your `query` which is supported by your `provider` to convert them to `expression tree` to run on your `Data Base` side.

all providers must support some methods by default called `Canonical Functions` ([Read More Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738626%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), and also you can define your `user defined function` and `stored procedure` as `edm functions` to use in `linq query` ([Read More Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456845%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456845%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

in addition you can use methods which is supported by providers and can be converted to `expression tree` which are in [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

and finally about your question, you can convert `UserID` and `ClassID` before your query, like this:

```
var UID = int.Parse(UserID);
var CID = int.Parse(ClassID);
var record = context.enrollments.SingleOrDefault
    (row => row.userId == UID && row.classId == CID);
```

Comment: Thank you Amir. I was stuck on this one quite a while, and couldn't fins an answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
  var iId = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
 var item = db.Items.Where(p => p.ItemID == iId ).FirstOrDefault();
```

To make that work you should convert your textbox value outside of the lambda expression.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `AsEnumerable()` as follows:

```
var record = context.enrollments.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(row => row.userId == Convert.ToInt32(UserID) && row.classId == Convert.ToInt32(ClassID));
```

Comment: There is already valid answer, and yours, with invalid code, is not working as you can see in others comment?

Comment: Sorry, very bad solution, `context.enrollments.AsEnumerable()` pulls all data into memory and only then selects just one. Be careful with this `AsEnumerable()` "fix".