# cant display the result linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have written a WPF program with c# that uses a SQL server database
here are my tables

[image: the sell tables]

[image: the clients table]

[image: the bank table]

the goal when the user checks the radiobutton, a listview named lv_factors shows the sell factors that are sold by check.
here is the code:

```
private void rb_sell_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var db = new mydataDataContext();
        var all = from p in db.tb_sellFacts
                  from r in db.tb_Clients
                  from s in db.tb_sellChecks
                  from t in db.tb_banks
                  from q in db.tb_checkStatus
                  where p.id_sellFact == s.id_sellfact && 
                        r.id == p.id_customer && 
                        t.id == s.id_bank && 
                        q.id == s.passed
                  select new dataTypes.AllChecks
                  {
                      bankname = t.name.ToString(),
                      id = p.id_sellFact.ToString(),
                      buydate = p.buydate,
                      checkaccount = s.checkaccount,
                      checkfee = s.paidprice.ToString(),
                      checknumber = s.checknumber,
                      checkstate = q.status,
                      custId = p.id_customer.ToString(),
                      idbank = s.id_bank.ToString(),
                      insertdate = p.insertdate,
                      passed = q.id.ToString(),
                      checkDate = s.checkdate,
                      CustName = r.family
                  };
        lv_factors.ItemsSource = all;

    }
```

but the listview doesn't show anything.can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tired `all.ToList()`?

Comment: yes it doesn't work.i have written another code for another table ,buyfactors  exactly the same columns and the same code like above and it works perfect but this one doesn't

Comment: Are you getting any values in variable all ? have you tried to use joins ?

Comment: yeah it gives some values but they dont display in listview. i checked the bindings for the columns in listview and they were correct.

Answer (score 0):

didnt get you `exception` by this query ? you must get exception, `.ToString()` can not be called in linq queries, it cant be converted to `expression tree`. i posted ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210526/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth/23274166#23274166) ) an answer says what can be called on `linq queries`.

Comment: No i dont get any exception at all. like i said above i have written another code excatly the same above for another table buywithcheck with exactly the same columns and same data type and it works fine