# linq Select Collection Column Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-query-syntax

I want select Col1 or Col2 by dynamic in linq command for example

```
var temp1= "Col1";
```

thank you for answer

I try by

```
((ICollection<SanadItem>)x.GetType().GetProperty(temp1).GetType()).Select(g =>...
```

but get error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method

```
public class class1 {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string Code {get; set;}
 public ICollection<Class2> Col1 {get; set;}
 public ICollection<Class2> Col2 {get; set;}
}

public class class2 {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public int Id2 {get; set;}
 public int Bed {get; set;}
 public int Bes {get; set;}
}
...
..
.

public class mycontext:dbcontext{
  public DbSet<Class1> class1 { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Class2> class2 { get; set; }
}

var db = new mycontext()
var qbase = db.class1;
        var qbase2 = qbase.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Code = x.Code,
            Name = x.Name,
           //--> I want select x.Col1 or x.Col2 by Dynamic but I cannot use library Linq.Dynamic
            items =  x.Col1.Where(xx => xx.Id2 == x.Id).GroupBy(b=>b.Id2).Select(y =>
                new
                { 
                    Bed = y.Sum(c=>c.Bed),
                    Bes = y.Sum(c => c.Bes),
                })                  
        });
```

Comment: Do you want the whole subselect or just the select part to be dyamic?

Comment: I want specified column in line items= x.Col1... I want specified Col1 for Col2 in linq

Comment: I mean, do you want the whole expression x.Col1.Where().GroupBy().Select() or just the Select() expression to be dynamic?

Comment: no all two query is same but Linq Command Where do on Filed Col1 or Col2

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
var qbase2 = qbase.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Code = x.Code,
            Name = x.Name,
            DynamicCol = (int)s.GetType().GetProperty("Col1").GetValue(x, null) ,
            //Remember to cast the dynamic column according to its datatype
            items =  x.Col1.Where(xx => xx.Id2 == x.Id).GroupBy(b=>b.Id2).Select(y =>
                new
                { 
                    Bed = y.Sum(c=>c.Bed),
                    Bes = y.Sum(c => c.Bes),
                })                  
        });
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use this `x.GetType()...` in `linq query`, because it will not be translated to `expression tree`, only methods can be used in `linq` which your provider can translate them to `expression tree` to run on `Data Base` side, you can read more about these, from post i added ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210526/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth/23274166#23274166)).

and about your question, if you insist on to use `reflection`, you have to fetch all of your data from `data base` first, and for this, you need to add `.ToList()` before your `.Select()` :

```
... var qbase2 = qbase.ToList().Select(x => new ...
```

OR

```
... var qbase = db.class1.ToList(); ....
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I need specified field befor to list because I have very record

Comment: you are welcome, but you can never do this in `linq to entities`

Comment: thank you amir but this is not linq to entities. this is (Code First) and do in database also other develepor find this problem and use dynamic linq

Comment: yes, finally i think, you have no way but dynamic linq

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works:

```
public class DynamicQuery<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> GetByFieldFilterObjectValue(IEnumerable<T> collection, string colName, object value)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> results = collection.Where(d => d.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(d, null).Equals(value));

            return results;
        }
    }
```

here is a sample of how I use it - dogs is a collection of Dog:

```
DynamicQuery<Dog> dogQuery = new DynamicQuery<Dog>();

var dogsSelected = dogQuery.GetByFieldFilterObjectValue(dogs, "Age", 2);
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I want get IQueryable no IEnumerable because Linq do on Database and database have very record

Answer (score 0):

Using answer from Co. Aden and Modifying it. Use AsEnumerable() before select.

```
var qbase2 = qbase.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Code = x.Code,
        Name = x.Name,
        DynamicCol = (int)s.GetType().GetProperty("Col1").GetValue(x, null) ,
        //Remember to cast the dynamic column according to its datatype
        items =  x.Col1.Where(xx => xx.Id2 == x.Id).GroupBy(b=>b.Id2).Select(y =>
            new
            { 
                Bed = y.Sum(c=>c.Bed),
                Bes = y.Sum(c => c.Bes),
            })                  
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This one.

```
var qbase2 = db.class1.select( x => new { x.Id, x.Code,x.Name}).ToList();
```

Comment: your command is not dynamic also my query in sample is complex but your code only select 3 column

Comment: dynamic means? what do you want to select, in here I select 3 columns.what do you need to do more?

Comment: the select may be change
var temp = "Family";
select (x=> new {x,id, x.code, temp}).Tolist();
also your select is simple but in top you can see select from collection

Comment: Please tell me what do you want to select, then I can help you.