# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
var query = from d in db.mytable
         where d.Code == int.Parse(WebUtils.GetQueryString("Code"))
         orderby d.PersonInfo
         select d;
```

i get the following error

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

i have tried to rewrite the int.Parse(WebUtils.GetQueryString("Code")) like this
 int intCode = int.TryParse(WebUtils.GetQueryString("OfferCode"));

but still got an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210526/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the 'Code' field to string instead of the query string to int.
This should works:

```
var queryString = WebUtils.GetQueryString("Code");
var query = from d in db.mytable
     where SqlFunctions.StringConvert(d.Code) == queryString 
     orderby d.PersonInfo
     select d;
```

There is no way to convert the string to int. EF doesn't know how to translate that to SQL if you use int.Parse

Comment: i did that. thanks. now i get another error - 

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetQueryString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

any thoughts on that?

Comment: thanks a lot. that works. may i ask something else. i have a similar problem with this bit of code

var query = from d in db.mytable
       select new
                                          {
         d.Code,
                                              
EditModeratedComments = "<a target='_blanc' href='Details.aspx?Code=" + r.Code + "'>change</a>"
                                          };

Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just parse your query string outside of the query context:

```
int code = int.Parse(WebUtils.GetQueryString("Code"));

var query = from d in db.mytable
         where d.Code == code
         orderby d.PersonInfo
         select d;
```

Comment: I did that and i got the following error - Input string was not in a correct format. i am using EF 6.1